# i use use multiple query it not display the correct information

Tags: mysql, sql

```
include "connect_db.php";
$sql = "SELECT
COUNT(*) AS numberOfRows,value,cf7_id,data_id,name,created

FROM
wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry

WHERE
wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'";





$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">id </div></th>
    <th width="98"> <div align="center">สร้างวันที่ </div></th>
    <th width="198"> <div align="center">cf7_id </div></th>
    <th width="97"> <div align="center">name </div></th>
    <th width="59"> <div align="center">value </div></th>

  </tr>
<?php
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><?php echo $result["id"];?></div></td>
    <td><?php echo $result["created"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result["cf7_id"];?></td>
    <td><div align="center"><?php echo $result["name"];?></div></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $result["value"];?></td>

  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table
```

>

count and detail in table it show now

why `count` show 12  but Table data is only one row.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB99f.png)

Information was created between `2017-11-27 08:54:39` and `2017-12-03 08:54:39` There are more than 1 information.

sorry i'm not good english
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfRows 
  FROM wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry 
  WHERE wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'
  UNION
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry 
  WHERE wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'
```

Comment: thank  but i show only Count()  Other information not shown.

Comment: ok  thanks, but I think multiple query one row and fetch all information in page..